# Question notification sound

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, notifications, audio

SE should give a  beeping *audible* notification for updates:

- when your question page gets a comment (to your question or other's answers)
- when someone comments with @yournanme to your comment
- when someone gives you an answer
- when someone votes up or down
- when someone answers your question
- when someone stars your question

It could be like a MIRC beep.

Comment: If this was implemented, there better be a way to turn it off. For some people, it would be an endless song.

Comment: And it should **default** to **off**. But really, no.

Comment: Sounds on a website are an *abomination*. This is the absolute last thing we need.

Comment: Not to mention that I often have about 30 Stack Overflow tabs open. Sure would be fun for 30 tabs to be generating beeps.

Comment: "SE should give a beeping audible notification for updates" No. No, it really shouldn't. If you want such an abomination to exist, create it on your own time, and keep it far, **far** away from me.

Comment: @meagar I disagree - Facebook notification sounds can be very useful whenever you're trying to keep track of a conversation.

Comment: @AndersonGreen Really not helping your case by trying to draw parallels between Stack Overflow and Facebook.

Answer (score 6):

I think the problem with this suggestion is that the speed in which a question is resolved is not necessarily instantaneous. Posts may take hours, days or even weeks to be resolved. In such a case, having an audible notification system is simply not feasible. Sure this is not always the case, but when implementing a feature like this, one has to take into consideration all possible consequences...

A feature like this would be much better suited to a chat like area and believe it or not, there is already a system like this in place on the [chat servers](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/). Communications there are meant to be faster than the usual

- post a question
- receive a comment requesting more information
- answer the comment
- edit the question
- get an answer
- comment on the answer requesting clarification
- etc...

Another thing to note here (speaking only for myself), is that people might not be 100% focused on the site the whole time that they are here. They might be at work, multi-tasking (as we do) and <kbd>alt+tabing</kbd> through multiple browser tabs only returning to Stack Overflow every so often to check for updates. So they might not want to be interrupted by a bleep every time someone mentions their name.

> ##Oh, so you're on Stack Exchange?
> [image]
> ##Let me sing you the song of my people...

Comment: " So they might not want to be interrupted by a bleep every time someone mentions their name."

Only in Russia would the internet censor or bleep everytime someone mentioned your name :)

Comment: ^ Russia on censorship laws.

Comment: @chr - I'd jump on board with this suggestion if the sound would be [this](http://www.dramabutton.com/) :P

Comment: If the notification sound could be toggled on and off, then this would certainly be a useful feature.